# VBA IF THEN Statement not working

Tags: vba, excel

I was just wondering if anyone can help. I have written the below for

1. To see first if the user has enough holiday to request a holiday
2. To see if the holiday they are about to request with the days they have left over will take them to more than the alloted time in this case 25.
3. If both of these are fine it should run the Sub NewBookingCheck

But what happens is that if they dont have enough time it will show up but if it is fine it wont contine through to run the "NewBookingCheck".

can anyone help me please?

I would also say that this is my first time at fully writing my own code so I appologise for any errors there may be

```
Sub TooMuchHoliday()

Dim daysremaining As Integer, daystaken As Integer, result As String, myValue As Variant

daystaken = Range("B13").Value

daysremaining = Range("D14").Value

If daysremaining <= 1 Then
    Msg = " You Do Not Have Enough Holiday! Would You Like To Continue ? " & Application.UserName

    Ans = MsgBox(Msg, vbYesNo)
    If Ans = vbNo Then
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                ThisWorkbook.Save
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                Application.Quit
                End If
    If Ans = vbYes Then
                    Sheets("Request Form").Select
                    Range("Employee3").ClearContents
                    Range("DateRequest").ClearContents
                    Range("Employee3") = Application.UserName
                    End If
End If

If daystaken >= 25 Then
    Msg = " You Do Not Have Enough Holiday! Would You Like To Continue ? " & Application.UserName

    Ans = MsgBox(Msg, vbYesNo)
    If Ans = vbNo Then
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                ThisWorkbook.Save
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                Application.Quit
                End If
    If Ans = vbYes Then
                    Sheets("Request Form").Select
                    Range("Employee3").ClearContents
                    Range("DateRequest").ClearContents
                    Range("Employee3") = Application.UserName
Else

NewBookingCheck.NewBookingCheck

End If


End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I think days taken and days remaining are the same thing... the critical one being days remaining. User1 has 25, they try to take 30 and the computer says no because it was more than they were allotted. User2 has 30, they try to take 30 and the computer says no because it was more than than allowed, so why was User2 given 30? Surely the critical path is their usage to zero from any number they were allotted?

Comment: And once they have only 1 day remaining they are not allowed to take it ?

Answer (score 1):

You missplaced an end if. Therefore the Else-statement belongs to the

```
If Ans = vbYes Then
```

if clause.

Change the last part of your code to the following:

```
If daystaken >= 25 Then
Msg = " You Do Not Have Enough Holiday! Would You Like To Continue ? " & Application.UserName

Ans = MsgBox(Msg, vbYesNo)
If Ans = vbNo Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            ThisWorkbook.Save
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            Application.Quit
            End If
If Ans = vbYes Then
                Sheets("Request Form").Select
                Range("Employee3").ClearContents
                Range("DateRequest").ClearContents
                Range("Employee3") = Application.UserName
                End If
Else

NewBookingCheck.NewBookingCheck

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below: -

```
Sub TooMuchHoliday()
Dim result          As String
Dim myValue         As Variant
Dim StrMsg          As String

'If you have <= instead of just < it will not let them take there last day, they should be able to use down to 0 not 1
If Range("D14").Value < 0 Then
    If MsgBox("You do not have enough annual leave remaining to fufil this request, would you still like to continue?", vbYesNo, "Not Enough") = vbNo Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ThisWorkbook.Save
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Application.Quit
    End If
End If

Sheets("Request Form").Select
Range("Employee3").ClearContents
Range("DateRequest").ClearContents
Range("Employee3") = Application.UserName

NewBookingCheck.NewBookingCheck

End Sub
```

Your checking that a user does not use more than their allowance (Remaining) and also does not use more than they are allowed (Taken). This implies that someone may be given more than 25 days annual leave and not be allowed to take it, so why would they be given it? The critical one to check is the remaining, if that goes below 0 then you have an issue.

Also you had `<= 1` which mean they couldn't take there last two days of annual leave (0 being a day, and 1 being a day)

If the application quits then the rest of the code is not run anyway so, if the alert needs to be fired and the user does not want to continue then it will close, else it will start your next bit of code.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but the sub that you have submitted just runs through and removes the dates requested only then for the NewBookingCheck To error as there are no values to reference.

Answer (score -2):

I future recommend you re-work and re-edit you questions here, since serious answers are approached accordingly and you want your code to be well-orginized and have good code appearance.
As for your question: you didn't attach the NewBookingCheck function so i guess it is somekind of: Private Sub NewBookingCheck() {...}
Try replacing your NewBookingCheck.NewBookingCheck line with:

```
Call NewBookingCheck()
```